# problems with starting my motocycle

Tags: starting, yamaha

I have a 1985 Yamaha Maxim XJ750.

I'm having problems starting it when it is not above 15 degrees Celsius.  It has lots of juice, compression is good, and it turns over fine.  It just takes forever for it to fire.  When its hot out it starts no problem.

Does anyone have any theories that might explain this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you edit your question and add any data about how it performs when you use the choke?  Cheers.

Comment: Some advice I was given about old bikes is to try cranking/kicking for a little but then let it sit for a few minutes while you get your gear together. Once you get back to it it'll be easier to start. I'm not sure why, but it seems to help.

Comment: Anywhere near your gas tank, carburetor or choke is there a switch to prime the bike? Maybe a little rotary one that says 'Off' 'On' or 'Prime'?